# reading arguments of $-method functions

Tags: r, redux, accessor, hiredis

I use `redux::hiredis` over ssh port-forwarding for some projects, and my network link occasionally glitches and the connection object fails (for known reasons). `redux` provides `R$reconnect()` for this, I'm trying to find a way to automate reconnecting (since it is only a manual process).

The most direct way is to use something like this, *everywhere*:

```r
R <- redux::hiredis()
res <- tryCatch(
  R$GET("quux"),
  error = function(e) {
    if (grepl("Failure communicating", conditionMessage(e))) {
      R$reconnect()
      R$GET("quux")
    } else stop(e)
  })
```

but that gets a bit onerous when used in many places (some I don't have easy access to change).

One thought I had is to super-class it and add an `$`-method for the new class. It takes some trickery to not be recursive, but something like this works, though it adds a `PING` to each call:

```r
redis_retry <- function(..., verbose = FALSE) {
  R <- redux::hiredis(...)
  class(R) <- c("redis_retry", class(R))
  R
}

`$.redis_retry` <- function(x, val) {
  val <- substitute(val)
  ocls <- class(x)
  on.exit(class(x) <- ocls, add = TRUE)
  class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "redis_retry")
  res <- tryCatch(x$PING(), error = function(e) e)
  if (inherits(res, "error")) {
    if (grepl("Failure communicating with", conditionMessage(res))) {
      x$reconnect()
      res <- tryCatch(x$PING(), error = function(e) e)
      if (inherits(res, "error")) stop(res)
      return(x[[val]])
    } else stop(res)
  }
  x[[val]]
}
```

```r
R2 <- redis_retry()
R2$SET("quux", 42)
# [Redis: OK]
R2$GET("quux")
# [1] "42"

### disconnect ssh port-forwarding
R2$GET("quux")
# Error in redis_connect_tcp(config$host, config$port, config$timeout) : 
#   Failed to create context: Unknown error

### reconnect ssh port-forwarding
R2$GET("quux")
# [1] "42"
```

I'd like to be able to skip the need for `x$PING()` internally. However, the intent of the `$`-accessor is only to return the function, so the following `("quux")` is unknown to `$`. For example, if I debug it,

```r
Browse[1]> debug at #3: val <- substitute(val)
Browse[2]> match.call()
`$.redis_retry`(x = R2, val = GET)
Browse[2]> where
where 1: `$.redis_retry`(R2, GET)
where 2: R2$GET
Browse[2]> sys.calls()
[[1]]
R2$GET
[[2]]
`$.redis_retry`(R2, GET)
```

and I don't see an easy way to determine the rest of the expression.

Perhaps I'm being dim about this, is there an easy way to wrap the `R2` object such that the original named-function is tried and, if it fails, `$reconnect()` and try again?

---

### Fake redis

If you don't have `redux` or an instance of redis available, here's a fake version that (I think) adequately resembles the `redis::hiredis` methods I'm demonstrating above:

```r
fake_redis <- function() {
  .counter <- 0L
  env <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
  env$GET <- function(ign) {
    if (.counter > 2) stop("counter is high")
    .counter <<- .counter + 1L
    "42"
  }
  env$reconnect <- function() .counter <<- 0L
  env
}
fakeR <- fake_redis()
fakeR$GET("quux")
# [1] "42"
fakeR$GET("quux")
# [1] "42"
fakeR$GET("quux")
# [1] "42"
fakeR$GET("quux")
# Error in fakeR$GET("quux") : counter is high
fakeR$reconnect()
fakeR$GET("quux")
# [1] "42"
```

Comment: Is there any other example we could test with that doesn't use `redux::hiredis`? I'm not sure I follow what's going on and since I can't run it, it's difficult to test.

Comment: Fair question, thanks @MrFlick. I've edited with a fake version which I hope adequately mimics the `redux` behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what if the `$` returned a function that wrapped the inner function. So like this

```
`$.redis_retry` <- function(x, val) {
  val <- substitute(val)
  ocls <- class(x)
  class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "redis_retry")
  function(...) {
    res <- tryCatch(x[[val]](...), error = function(e) e)
    if (inherits(res, "error")) {
      x$reconnect()
      message("reconnecting")
      res <- x[[val]](...)
    }
    res
  }
}
```

I tested with the `fake_redis` function you provided

```
redis_retry <- function(..., verbose = FALSE) {
  R <- fake_redis(...)
  class(R) <- c("redis_retry", class(R))
  R
}
fakeR <- redis_retry()
fakeR$GET("quux")
# [1] "42"
> fakeR$GET("quux")
[1] "42"
fakeR$GET("quux")
# [1] "42"
fakeR$GET("quux")
# reconnecting
# [1] "42"
fakeR$reconnect()
# [1] 0
fakeR$GET("quux")
# [1] "42"
```

Comment: This worked with the real `redux`-based problem as well, perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I think you can probably move the class renaming stuff outside of the inner function. I forgot to test it but probably doesn't matter too much.

Comment: yes that works as well

Comment: I found I needed to add `class(x) <- c("redis_retry", class(x))` inside the inner function immediately before `res` is returned, otherwise the second failure would not use this adjusted `$`-method.